# How to install Julia in an anaconda environment?

Tags: julia, anaconda, conda

One of the main features of Anaconda is that it is language agnostic as stated in their [blog](http://continuum.io/blog/conda_packaging):

> You can create environments of any binary dependency tree (different
>   versions of Python, R, Julia, etc.).

Recently I switched from using virtualenv to Anaconda in Python, so I was curious to try Julia in an Anaconda environment. However, I couldn't find instructions explicit enough to install Julia successfully. First, I tried naively `conda create -n julia-test julia`. Obviously, it didn't work. Then I [found](https://binstar.org/wakari1/julia) at binstar.org a Julia package (version 0.3) with the code

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/wakari1 julia
```

However, I don't want to install Julia outside of a specific virtual environment, so I changed it to:

```
conda create -n julia-test -c https://conda.binstar.org/wakari1 julia
```

It didn't throw errors but ultimately failed to start the Julia interpreter.

So, what is the correct way of installing Julia (0.2, preferably) in an anaconda environment?

**UPDATE**

As of March 2018, Julia v0.6.1 is available for linux-64 on the conda-forge channel:

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/julia

It has been set up to install packages inside `<env_prefix>/share/julia/site`, to maintain isolation from the user's `~/.julia` user's home directory.

`conda create -n julia -c conda-forge julia`

Comment: I don't understand why you'd need to/want to install Julia in this?

Comment: Because I don't want to install and test Julia packages without some kind of virtual environment. Pretty much the same idea of using virtualenv in Python.

Comment: Julia can be installed in any location, and packages are by default installed in ~/.julia but you can change that just by setting the environmental variable JULIA_PKGDIR. Don't know anything about anaconda though sorry.

Comment: No problem. I know you can choose the installation directory, but that doesn't prevent issues with multiple packages installed and conflicts with different versions.

Comment: @RobertSmith, Julia is too new, we do not worry about package conflicts *yet*. We're currently *developing* the packages.

Comment: @juliohm But then the statement in the continuum analytics blog is false?

Comment: I'm not following the Anaconda development closely, sorry.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The blog post was indicating that conda is general enough to allow packages of any type. There are no packages for Julia yet (except for the one you found in the Wakari channel, which is specific to Wakari).

Building a conda package for Julia and probably isn't difficult. Building a streamlined way to convert Julia packages into conda packages is a bit more work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know if this feature is in the works?

Comment: For people interested, Aaron answered my question here: https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/d/msg/anaconda/Td46J2kmehI/IU0XKewbEw0J Basically, the Anaconda team welcomes pull requests.

Answer (score 35):

As of August 2017, Julia v0.5.2 is available on the conda-forge channel:

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/julia

It has been set up to install packages inside `<env_prefix>/share/julia/site`, to maintain isolation from the user's `~/.julia` user's home directory.

`conda create -n julia -c conda-forge julia`

Comment: This doesn't appear to work anymore, when I try to run this, I get a PackagesNotFoundError

Answer (score 9):

Julia 0.4.5 (not the current latest 0.5.0) is now available from the bioconda channel.
Using anaconda (python 3.6 version) and following instructions in [bioconda](https://bioconda.github.io/) :

```
# In this order    
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --add channels defaults
conda config --add channels r
conda config --add channels bioconda

conda install julia
```

So to create the corresponding virtual environment:

```
conda create -n julia-env julia
```

Nonetheless, I did not see any additional julia libraries available yet.

Comment: Version 0.5.2 is available deom bioconda now. See here https://anaconda.org/bioconda/julia

Answer (score 5):

As of Jan 2022, Anaconda suggests using;

`conda install -c conda-forge julia`

See: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/julia

Comment: Any idea why I'm getting an PackagesNotFoundError. Is there a new way to install julia from within conda? Is this a miniconda support issue on my side?